# Why is a filesystem in linux not classified as a device driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

This question came up while I was reading the book 'Linux Device Drivers'.
Every device driver is mapped to a physical device and since filesystems in linux can be associated with memory I got a bit confused.
I think this needs a bit more justice in order to understand drivers better. Looking for more arguments other than what the book specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesystem is actually device agnostic as most file systems can be implemented on most block devices.

Device drivers tell the kernel how to use the hardware device to address (read/write/seek) its data, whilst the filesystem modules tell it how to represent files and directories over a block device.

You could analogically think of the block device as a house structure and the filesystem as what is inside the house such as the furniture and decoration.  The house structure doesn't determine what you put in it or how it's decorated.